# How could I solve this issue, in JavaFX? I assume it has to do with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

So I'm currently working on building a SerialPort reader, but for some reason, when I start my app and access the window with the SerialPort terminal, my app suddenly stops working. I assume it has to do with multithreading in JavaFX. Here is the section of the code pertaining to the reading and accessing of the button which opens up the terminal handling the receiving of data.

```java
button2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        receiveTerminal = new TextArea();
        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        StackedAreaChart analysisChart = new StackedAreaChart(xAxis,yAxis);
        SerialPort port = SerialPort.getCommPort("COM1");
        port.openPort();
        BorderPane window = new BorderPane();
        window.setLeft(receiveTerminal);
        window.setRight(analysisChart);
        ScrollBar scroll = new ScrollBar();
        window.setBottom(scroll);
        Scene secondScene = new Scene(window, 600, 480);
        Stage newWindow = new Stage();
        newWindow.setTitle("Control Panel");
        newWindow.setScene(secondScene);
        newWindow.show();
        port.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_READ_SEMI_BLOCKING, 0, 0);
        InputStream in = port.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        receiveTerminal.appendText("Data is" + line);
                    } 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I tried different options, the last option being the `Platform.runLater()` option. Before that I was trying to use the `SerialPortDataListener`, but for some reason converting the byte streams didn't seem to work.

Comment: Your `Platform.runLater(...)` isn't doing anything, since you are already on the FX Application Thread. `readLine()` is a blocking call, so it must be executed on a background thread (execute the entire loop there). `appendText(...)` modifies a UI element, so you must schedule that on the FX Application Thread, using `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

You are blocking the application thread. Read about Java/JavaFX concurrency before you start such an ambitious project. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm